# Convert dataframe column into integers from within loop

Tags: python, dataframe

I'm trying loop through a folder of csv's and put them into a dataframe, change certain columns into an integer, before passing them through a Django model. Here is my code:

```
import glob
import pandas as pd   
path = 'DIV1FCS_2017/*/*'

for fname in glob.glob(path):
    df = pd.read_csv(fname)
    df['Number'].apply(pd.to_numeric)
```

I am receiving the following: ValueError: Unable to parse string

Does anybody know if I can convert a column of strings into integers using pd.to_numeric from within a loop? Outside of the loop it seems to work properly.

Comment: Are you sure there are only numbers in that field ?

Comment: please, provide sample of data in textual form so we can test it

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably have some non-numbers data stored in your dataframe, and that's what's casuing the error.
You can examine your data and make sure everything's fine. In the meantime, you can also do pd.to_numeric(errors="ignore") to ignore errors for now.